# Seaborn distplot and countplot displaying incorrect y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a simple dataset created using NLTK's FreqDist function, and have successfully converted the distribution to a pandas dataframe. When visualizing that dataframe using seaborn, I get a weird output on the plot itself.

```
fdist = FreqDist(words)
fdist = fdist.most_common(20)

# Create a dataframe representing occurences of the most common keywords
df_words = pd.DataFrame(data=fdist,columns=['word','occurences'])
print(df_words)
```

[image]

```
sns.displot(data=df_words,x='word',y='occurences')
plt.xticks(rotation=45,horizontalalignment='right');
```

[image]

My expectation is that the chart uses the numbers in the occurences column as the values on the y-axis, which it sort of does, but it doesn't format the chart like any histogram I've ever seen, and I cannot figure out how to correct the output. I've tried using `sns.countplot` instead, but it gives a different but equally unusable output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have provided the aggregated data to the function instead of the non-aggregated data. See the following example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"word": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]})
```

Using `sns.displot(df, x="word")` gives the following plot:

[image]

While using `sns.displot(df["word"].value_counts().reset_index(), x="index", y="word")` gives the following plot:

[image]

So you could either using the non-aggregated dataset in combination with `sns.displot`, or use `sns.barplot` with the aggregated dataset, which would give the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Using 'sns.barplot' gave the correct output. I didn't realize there was a distinction between 'barplot' and 'histplot'. Thanks for the solution! (I gave an upvote but karma limit won't let me actually give credit)